# How to insert 5 uploaded files in 5 different columns of SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to take 5 images input from user and save it to 5 different columns as ([userID (foreign key from UserInfo Table], image1, image2, image3, image4, image5) of a SQL Server table.

Can anyone tell me the code for this? Below is the code for input of 5 images.

```
Private Sub BrowseMultipleFilesButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BrowseMultipleFilesButton.Click
    Dim OpenFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter =
     "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" +
     "All files (*.*)|*.*"

    OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
    Dim index As New Integer

    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select Photos"

    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length > 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select no more than 5 files")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length < 5 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select 5 files")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For Each file As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            Dim imageControl As New PictureBox()
            imageControl.Height = 100
            imageControl.Width = 100
            Dim myCallback As New Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(AddressOf ThumbnailCallback)
            Dim myBitmap As New Bitmap(file)
            Dim myThumbnail As Image = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(96, 96, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero)
            imageControl.Image = myThumbnail

            PhotoGallary.Controls.Add(imageControl)
            index = OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex()
        Next
        btn_Save.Enabled = True
        BrowseMultipleFilesButton.Enabled = False

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't really see where you are performing your query

Comment: you could add the path of each image to an array, then decide how large the array is and dynamically alter your sql to respectively insert each image path into the right field but I don't really know what programming language you are using, I would guess visual basic but I'm not sure

Comment: I m asking, where should I perform query?

Comment: yeh right I m using VB.Net

Comment: Where are you uploading the files to?

Comment: Is there something fundamentally different about the 4th image as compared to, say, the 2nd image? If not, there ought to be a *single* column that contains these images (multiple rows instead).  Having numbered columns is usually a sign of a broken model.

Comment: I would like to add to that that saving images straight into database isn't the best way to do it either, saving your images somewhere on the filesystem and saving the path in the database is how I would do it

Comment: according to my application Every user has to upload 5 images with his ID so the table has these fields(ID, UserInfoID, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5)  [where UserInfoID is the foreignkey from the UserInfoTable)

Comment: I think it may be save in listview before inserting in SQL-Database.

Comment: is there any variable that stores the filepath for your image before trying to upload?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to save your images in your database you could use the bulkcolumn from open rowset statement
The query would be:

```
Insert Into MyTable(userID, image1, image2, image3, image4, image5)
   Select @user_id, BulkColumn 
   from Openrowset (Bulk @image1path, Single_Blob) as image1,
BulkColumn 
   from Openrowset (Bulk @image2path, Single_Blob) as image2,
BulkColumn 
   from Openrowset (Bulk @image3path, Single_Blob) as image3,
BulkColumn 
   from Openrowset (Bulk @image4path, Single_Blob) as image4
BulkColumn 
   from Openrowset (Bulk @image5path, Single_Blob) as image5;
```

Keep in mind to dynamically create your query with @user_id is the id you get from your UserInfo table and @imageXpath is always a filepath on the user's system in the form of 'directory/directory/../filename.ext' surrounded by single quotes

You would create and execute this query after your foreach statement dynamically (if you have less files you don't need all 5 inserts so your insert into mytable(fieldname,...) would have less fields and you would have less bulkcolumn statements

source = https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

IMPORTANT NOTE:

> OPENROWSET permissions are determined by the permissions of the user
>   name that is being passed to the OLE DB provider. To use the BULK
>   option requires ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS permission.

If you don't have these permissions set up correctly find a different way of storing your images and save the filepaths to your image in the database in a varchar column instead

Comment: Let me stress again that I advise against doing this as you are now staring large amounts of data into a table which could lower performance also you will need to set up your database to be able to handle this kind of data